How do I find and kill long-running transaction in MySQL
Our app has some long-running operations that are wrapped in a transaction, within such transaction it performs dozens of fast queries.
Recently we encountered a problem with one of such transactions - it updated a lot of resources and therefore acquired LOCKs on them, which prevents other update operations to be performed on these resources until that long-running transaction finishes.
Question:
How can we find that transaction's process ID and kill it if we need to?
I wanted to find it via SHOW PROCESSLIST output (maybe just find a command that is executing long, for example) but this seems problematic: as I understand that started transaction will have in the Sleep state and it will not have any other details, and given we have a pool of persistent connections to DB (which also have Sleep state and show long execution time) I am not sure how I can find that specific connection that I want to kill.
This is for the future reference, the transaction we had a problem with already finished.
Hope it makes sense.

i think the pt-kill command may be what you are after (you may need to install)

If it is not obvious from PROCESSLIST, perhaps it is the app code between SQL statements?

You can get currently running transaction details from information_schema.innodb_trx table:
SELECT
    trx_id,
    trx_mysql_thread_id,
    trx_state,
    trx_started,
    trx_wait_started,
    trx_query,
    trx_operation_state
FROM
    information_schema.innodb_trx
WHERE
    trx_state = 'RUNNING'
ORDER BY
    trx_started;

The useful columns for the purpose of the question above are:

trx_mysql_thread_id - this is the process ID that you can pass to KILL {process id}; command to kill the transaction.
trx_started - shows the datetime of when the transaction was started, useful to determine which transaction is the one I am looking for.

Also, it might be useful to JOIN information_schema.processlist table to get the current execution time of each transaction (for convenience of determining which is the longest transaction running):
SELECT 
    trx.trx_id,
    trx.trx_mysql_thread_id,
    trx.trx_started,
    p.TIME
FROM 
    information_schema.innodb_trx trx
    JOIN information_schema.processlist p ON trx.trx_mysql_thread_id = p.ID
WHERE 
    trx.trx_state = 'RUNNING';

You can grab more columns that you'll find useful there.

Try the below statement please:
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_trx` ORDER BY `trx_started`;
kill [trx_mysql_thread_id];

